# Has any performance advantage compiling projects in parallel with a multithread program instead of using a single thread program?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have to create with Java a program capable of perform n builds for a certain android project. Currently, I’m using the class [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) and [Process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) in order to execute the command *"./gradlew assembleRelease"*, which executes the task *"assembleRelease"* invoking [gradle](http://gradle.org), thus allowing to build the project and outputs a signed APK.

As I’ve already said, the program needs to execute n builds (1.000-4.000) for a certain android project. So, my question is:

**Is there any advantage (time performing) in creating a multithreading program, which distribute these builds among n threads (managed by a [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) for instance), rather than doing all the builds in a single thread?** And how can I know what is the optimal number of threads to run asynchronously?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing this yourself in Java, I would suggest looking at existing solutions.

If you do not have a build server, this would be a great tool to handle this as it knows all about running builds in parallel!

For thousands of jobs, I would recommend a scripting solution to create and maintain the jobs, as well as a version control repository to let the jobs get the sources from when changed (like github).

I have found Jenkins with the Job DSL plugin to work quite nice for this.  See https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Could I be able with this DSL plugin hit an endpoint and retrieve a JSON which will set the number of builds to execute, among other things like a client id, etc?

Comment: Probably. It is just a groovy script being run so I would expect it to be possible.